# Resource with translations is not deploying

Tags: silverlight, deployment, resources

I have a `Silverlight 4` application which is hosted in asp.net website as `ClientBin`.

I have two files: 
`MyAppResources` and `MyAppResources.pl-PL`

When I locally use my application everything goes ok - I have translated fields, but when I use this application hosted on the server every field has a text from main resource file.

I set :

- `Embeded Resource` and `Do not copy` to `MyAppResources`
- `Resource` and `Copy always` to `MyAppResources.pl-PL`

I build my application in release mode, and copy xap from `ClientBin` folder.
Then I copy that xap to `ClientBin` at server.

Could someone help me with that?

**Edit**

Culture of the server is en-GB. Culture of my station is pl-PL.

When I run app from the server I haven't translation, but I have dates in calendar in polish format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set :

```
MyAppITResources.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
```

on the **ApplicationStartup**

and now it works fine.